# Hide dialog output in bash scrollback (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dialog

I use the following script to display a dialog in the bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
TFILE=/tmp/habitat_resp_`whoami`.$$
dialog --menu "Commander?" 20 50 10 \
             1       "MySQL" \
             2       "Apache" \
             3       "Postfix" \
             4       "Dovecot" \
             5       "Owncloud" \
             2> $TFILE

         # get response
         RESPONSE=$(cat $TFILE)
echo $RESPONSE
clear
```

The problem is, when I scroll up, i can still see the dialog in my scrollback. I want it like vi. I open my script and the dialog appears and if the script is over you cant see the dialog in scrollback.

How can this be achieved?

Regards
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `--keep-tite` option, which tells `dialog` to use the "alternative screen", which doesn't participate in terminal scrollback. This produces some slightly annoying display artefacts, but possibly not as annoying as polluting your scrollback.